# How to extract a string from last line in a text file -windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch, script

I have a .txt file in this format

```
123|abc|23456
234|rsty|68589
890|gfyu|5679
TRAILER|3|
```

How do i extract "3" from the last line enclosed between "TRAILER|" and "3" ? Need help.

Comment: Is this a one off task? If not, are there always 4 lines in the file?

Answer (score 2):

If there are always 4 lines as shown with "TRAILER" in the last line:

```
for /f "skip=3 tokens=2 delims=|" %l in (List.txt) do @echo %l
```

If there can be any number of lines with the "TRAILER" line being present anywhere:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=|" %l in ('type List.txt ^| find "TRAILER"') do @echo %l
```

`for /?` will teach you what the *skip*, *tokens* and *delims* options mean, although it shouldn't be hard to figure out. Also remember to double each % sign while using the commands in a batch file.

Comment: Hehe. I was waiting for a reply to my comment before answering, so you beat me to it ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill: I knew you would have an answer ready as well. :) Anyway I tried to cover the scenarios I could think of but who knows, the OP might get back with a completely different set of requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the answer already given, you could install [Gnu on Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) and do

```
tail -n 1 <your file here> | awk -F"|" "{print $2;}"
```